# Modified loop-single-forum.php to work inside of a sidebar Widget, not working on some site pages

Tags: loop, single, forum

So I took `loop-single-forum.php`, copied it and renamed it, fixed it so the site is calling the copy and then removed what I did not need from it to place it in a sidebar widget. It works beautifully on every screen on the site. Except for two and I can't figure out why. IF you're on the Topic's List Page the widget shows Nothing at all in the Categories Tab and then IF you're in an actual Topic it shows the **"Oh bother! No forums found"**. Looking to figure out what I could have left out in the code as I'm honestly using the existing code minus a few bits that I didn't need.

`loop-single-forum.php` -

```
    <?php

        /**
        * Forums Loop - Single Forum
        *
        * @package bbPress
        * @subpackage Theme
        */

    ?>

    <tr id="bbp-forum-<?php bbp_forum_id(); ?>" <?php bbp_forum_class(); ?>>

        <td class="bbp-forum-info">

            <?php do_action( 'bbp_theme_before_forum_title' ); ?>

            <a class="bbp-forum-title" href="<?php bbp_forum_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php bbp_forum_title(); ?>"><?php bbp_forum_title(); ?></a>

            <?php do_action( 'bbp_theme_after_forum_title' ); ?>

        </td>

    </tr><!-- bbp-forum-<?php bbp_forum_id(); ?> -->
```